# Perfectly align a number in a folded corner of a square with rounded borders

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/zander_pope/vb0s4jer/
I wanna achieve something like this with the minimum amount of divs and css(html and css only). All the corners should be rounded even the fold.

```
<div class="square">
<div class="inner">
    <p>4</p>
</div>
</div>

.square{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.inner{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 30px 30px 0 0;
border-color: #ff0000 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: If you add an `overflow: hidden` to your `.square` the `.inner` will have a rounded-corner too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add  `overflow:hidden;` in `.square` class:

```
.square{   
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    border-radius:4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="square">
    <div class="square fold"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.square {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:blue;
   border-radius:4px;
}

.square .fold {
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 29%, 29% 0);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 29%, 29% 0);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vb0s4jer/6/